# How to pass params to nested child in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I need your help to solve a problem with components in Handlebars.

I have a nested component that needs to receive a param from its parent but I can't realize how.

My parent component json data

```
{
  "_template": "SocialBar.hbs",
  "isSocialNameShown": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "_template": "/social/SocialLink.hbs",
      "href": "https://www.facebook.com/",
      "socialService": "facebook"
    },
    {
      "_template": "/social/SocialLink.hbs",
      "href": "https://twitter.com/",
      "socialService": "twitter"
    },
    {
      "_template": "/social/SocialLink.hbs",
      "href": "https://www.linkedin.com/",
      "socialService": "linkedin"
    }
  ]
}
```

Template file

```
<div class="SocialBar">
    {{#with items}}
        <ul class="SocialBar-items">
            {{#each this}}
                <li class="SocialBar-items-item">{{this}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/with}}
</div>
```

the nested component

```
<a class="SocialLink" href="{{href}}">
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="#mono-icon-{{socialService}}"></use>
    </svg>
    {{#if isSocialNameShown}}
        <span class="sr-only">{{socialService}}</span>
    {{/if}}
</a>
```

But in child component the **isSocialNameShown** is undefined. If I pass it directly inside each item, it works but I need to take it from the parent param

```
"items": [
    {
      "_template": "/social/SocialLink.hbs",
      "href": "https://www.facebook.com/",
      "socialService": "facebook",
      "isSocialNameShown": true
    },
]
```

I tried something like  `"isSocialNameShown": "{{isSocialNameShown}}"` inside each item but I don't know how to do it.

Anybody can help me, please?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is more than just Handlebars being used here. What library is converting the `_template` path values into executable templates?

Comment: I'm trying Brightspot CMS. So I'm not sure what it uses. This is all I know https://docs.brightspot.com/4.2/en/theme-guide/data-files/special-keys.html#UUID-aad35ee7-22da-7dea-f8da-2cff02b198cd

Comment: Your issue seems specific to the Brightspot implementation. Unfortunately, I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your attention. I will ask Brightspot for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to pass params to child components in Brightspot CMS. There are helpers called `set` and `get` to make that.

Example:

```
{{#set lastName="Forkbeard"}}
    {{include "Child.hbs"}}
{{/set}}
```

Given the above usage of `set`, the value may be used in `Child.hbs` as follows:

```
"Sweyn {{get "lastName"}}" equals "Sweyn Forkbeard".
```